# Googleapis ограничения API key

Tags: android, google-maps-api

http клиентом(HttpURLConnection) запрашиваю ссылку 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

если ограничить YOUR_API_KEY на использованию только на андроид приложении (указать имя пакета и sha1) то на запрос перестает отвечать.

Получается в моем случае нельзя ограничивать ключ на использование только в конкретном приложении?

Answer (score 1):

В своем вопросе вы сами и ответили на него. Если вы задаете в ограничениях конкретное имя пакета android-приложения, то API Key будет работать только там. Если вам требуется ключ для разных проектов - уберите ограничение.

Comment: Проект то один и тот же, просто в приложении я делаю get запрос на получение адреса.

Не использую класс Geocoder, а на прямую шлю get запрос т.к. Geocoder не всегда работает..